# Creating a Label Dynamically using Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, label, postback, pageload

I am using Aspnet, and i need to create an undetermined number of labels for one specific page.
I have a button that calls a function which generates a label dynamically using javascript:

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
> function create() {
>    var newlabel = document.createElement("box1");
>
>            ...
>
>   document.getElementById("MainContent_revenuestreams").appendChild(newlabel);
> }
> </script>
> ```

What happens is that after the label is created he only shows on the webpage for about 2-3 seconds and after that it disapears (i think that the postback eliminates its content).

I would like to know how can i avoid this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`document.createElement(type)` - `type` must be a html tag name like: div, table, p.

In your case:

```
var newLabel = document.createElement("label");
```

Then you set attributes for this element (`for` - most important in label, id, name).

Finally:

```
newLabel.appendChild(document.createTextNode("This is where label caption should be"));
document.getElementById("MainContent_revenuestreams").appendChild(newLabel);
```

Some links:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createtextnode.asp

As you see `box1` is not a valid argument for `document.createElement(type)`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to return false to cancel the postback of the button:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript: create();return false;"/>
```

Also note that `document.createElement("box1");` will create a `<box1></box1>` element which is probably not what you want. You should change `"box1"` to `"label"` or `"span"`

Comment: How do you know if he doesn't do it that way? The main problem is that `document.createElement(...)` is called with wrong argument.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo because he says that the label appears on the page and then it disappears. Since he is creating it with a button it is very likely that the postback causes the label to disappear

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo Also, `<box1></box1>` will probably be ignored by the browser so the text will appear.

Comment: In fact it might appear and disappear as described by @Chazz1 - I've seen that. Why it happens? I guess it's some kind of artifact from browser engine trying to do something useful with string passed to `document.createElement(...)`. However, your answer is also good, but apparently it wasn't the problem with page reload this time. So upvote for you.

Answer (score 0):

Add OnClientClick="addNewlabel();return false;"

function addNewlabel() {

```
var NumOfRow++;
var mainDiv=document.getElementById('MainDiv'); 
var newDiv=document.createElement('div'); 
newDiv.setAttribute('id','innerDiv'+NumOfRow); 
var newSpan=document.createElement('span'); 
newSpan.innerHTML="Your Label Name"; 
// append the span
newDiv.appendChild(newSpan); 
mainDiv.appendChild(newDiv);
```

}